is TCP socket open TIME_WAIT state even useful for Http requests?
I use C#, and there are many articles talking about how misusing HttpClient will cause socket exhaustion. Because after even the http connection is closed, the socket is in a TIME_WAIT state to handle delayed packets. I want to know if those packets are useful?
var httpClient = new HttpClient()
var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
//rest of the code

The rest of the code executes with response data we have, and how can the delayed packets even prove useful here? The code using the response is already executed. Shouldn't the response wait same amount as the sockets so that we get all the response.

HttpClientHandler doesn't close the connection immediately in case you reconnect to the same server. Not reusing the HttpClientHandler means that you lose track of that and open another connection.

okay, that way re-using the httpclient (its internal handler) is useful. But the reason why the socket stays open (for delayed packets) is not relevant/useful to us?

"...  to handle delayed packets. I want to know if those packets are useful?" - the point of TIME_WAIT is to make sure that delayed packets from one TCP connection don't cause confusion with new connections. This is not about "packets being useful".

in that case, when I reuse same httpClient handlers, I am susceptible to TCP connection confusion? @SteffenUllrich

@subject-q: There is nothing you need to do in your program to take care of such confusion. This is done by the OS and TIME_WAIT is the mechanism for this.

Note that the client enters TIME_WAIT only if the client closes the TCP connection first. If the server closes the connection first (ie, the response has a Connection: close header) then the client does not enter TIME_WAIT.

Any IP packets received during the TIME_WAIT phase are handled by the OS.
Once your application releases/closes the socket the OS will no longer pass the data to your application.  Any attempt to read from the socket will be met with an error.
Data that is still coming in will be dropped by the OS.  The application has, by closing the socket, declared that any data still being sent from the other end is no longer of interest.  If the application still wanted data from the other endpoint, then it would not have closed the socket.
